Team Scheduling 8 Teams, 5 Pitches, 4 rounds no repeats
I have to schedule a tournament.  I've spent days on this with a degree in physics, no further forward.
Question
There are 8 teams, there are 5 pitches, and there are only 4 rounds.  All teams must play in each round.  Any team may play any other team.
Constraints.
No team shall play each other twice.
No team play on the same pitch twice.
Can it be solved?

So, pre-set schedules for round-robin tournaments exist and are plentiful on the web -- is there a reason you can't just take one and chop off the last three rounds?

Yes,  because they dont lead to a solution or I wouldn't be asking.

Ah, I see -- repeating the playing surface is the problem, then? (Since the prebuilt schedules aren't going to care about that.)

So I basically took the first three rounds of a RR schedule I had laying around, which should probably be equivalent to one you've found, and shuffled them around the five playing fields, and then picked games out of the other rounds that worked so the last round doesn't match the pattern.  (I did have to swap two games in round three from my first attempt.) So I believe this works:
1-8 2-7 3-6 4-5 x-x
x-x 3-5 4-8 2-6 1-7
2-5 1-6 x-x 7-8 3-4
4-6 x-x 5-7 1-3 2-8
I don't know how general this could be -- there will be two fields that will have three games in the first three rounds; one can take round four off, but the other will have to play so that is the main constraint on round 4.

You Sir/Maam  Are a gentleman and a scholar,  works out beautifully.  I was literally resorting to brute forcing an answer always left with one team repeating a pitch.  20 combinations of that solution work and I didnt even stumble on one of them in 3 days of brainstorming
